# I am not able to fill a select inside a form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working with a form with two select fields. One of them is asociated with a change event. I use Ajax to send the ID to other php document to process the data and execute a query. 
The query works fine, I see the result of the echo using firebug. The problem is that I am not able to load the values of the query to my ('#municipio') select in the form. Could you guide me please?

I post my code:

1) Here is my html + js & ajax code

```
<?php
//Activamos el almacenamiento en el buffer
ob_start();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["nombre"]))
{
  header("Location: login.html");
}
else
{
require 'header.php';
if ($_SESSION['gestion']==1)
{
?>
<!--Contenido-->
      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">        
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                          <h1 class="box-title">Clientes <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnagregar" onclick="mostrarform(true)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar</button></h1>
                        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- centro -->
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive" id="listadoregistros">
                        <table id="tbllistado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                          <thead>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                            <th>Forma de pago</th>                          
                            <th>Provincia</th>
                            <th>Municipio</th>
                            <th>T.L. Fiscal</th>
                            <th>Nombre comercial</th>
                            <th>Zona</th>
                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                            <th>Móvil</th>
                            <th>Fax</th>
                            <th>Contacto</th>
                            <th>Domicilio 1</th>
                            <th>Domicilio 2</th>
                            <th>Población</th>
                            <th>C.P</th>
                            <th>NIF/CIF</th>
                            <th>Representante</th>
                            <th>CCC</th>
                            <th>IBAN</th>
                            <th>Recargo Equivalencia (S/N)</th>
                            <th>Descuento comercial</th>                    
                            <th>Descuento pronto pago</th>  
                            <th>Financiación</th>                                   
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>                            
                          </tbody>
                          <tfoot>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                            <th>Forma de pago</th>
                            <th>Provincia</th>
                            <th>Municipio</th>                          
                            <th>T.L. Fiscal</th>
                            <th>Nombre comercial</th>
                            <th>Zona</th>
                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                            <th>Móvil</th>
                            <th>Fax</th>
                            <th>Contacto</th>
                            <th>Domicilio 1</th>
                            <th>Domicilio 2</th>
                            <th>Población</th>
                            <th>C.P</th>
                            <th>NIF/CIF</th>
                            <th>Representante</th>
                            <th>CCC</th>
                            <th>IBAN</th>
                            <th>Recargo Equivalencia (S/N)</th>
                            <th>Descuento comercial</th>                    
                            <th>Descuento pronto pago</th>  
                            <th>Financiación</th>   
                          </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="height: 1000px;" id="formularioregistros">
                        <form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>T.L Fiscal:</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="idcliente" id="idcliente">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tlfiscal" id="tlfiscal" maxlength="30" placeholder="Razón social de la empresa" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Nombre:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nombre comercial de la empresa">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Zona:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zona" id="zona" maxlength="25" placeholder="Zona de la empresa">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Teléfono:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" maxlength="15" placeholder="Indicar el nº de teléfono fijo">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Móvil:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="movil" id="movil" maxlength="15" placeholder="indicar el nº de móvil">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Fax:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fax" id="fax" maxlength="15" placeholder="indicar el nº de fax de la empresa">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Contacto:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contacto" id="contacto" maxlength="30" placeholder="indicar la persona de contacto">
                          </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Provincia:</label>
                            <select id="provincia" name="provincia" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                            <option value="">Selecciona la provincia del cliente</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>    
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Municipio:</label>
                            <select id="municipio" name="municipio" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                            <option value="">Selecciona provincia primero</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>                              
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Domicilio 1:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domicilio1" id="domicilio1" maxlength="60" placeholder="indicar el domicilio de la empresa" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Domicilio 2:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domicilio2" id="domicilio2" maxlength="60" placeholder="indicar el domicilio alternativo de la empresa si lo hubiera">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Población:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poblacion" id="poblacion" maxlength="30" placeholder="indicar la población del cliente" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>C.P:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cp" id="cp" maxlength="5" placeholder="indicar el código postal del cliente">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>NIF/CIF:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idfiscal" id="idfiscal" maxlength="11" placeholder="indicar el NIF o CIF del cliente" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Representante:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="representante" id="representante" maxlength="30" placeholder="Representante del cliente">
                          </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Forma de pago:</label>
                            <select id="idpago" name="idpago" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required></select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Código Cuenta Cliente:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ccc" id="ccc" maxlength="23" placeholder="Indicar nº de cuenta del cliente">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>IBAN:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iban" id="iban" maxlength="38" placeholder="Indicar el IBAN del cliente">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>BIC:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bic" id="bic" maxlength="11" placeholder="Indicar el BIC del cliente">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Recargo de equivalencia:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="re" id="re" maxlength="2" placeholder="Indicar si el cliente tiene o no recargo de equivalencia" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Precio aplicable:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precioaplicable" id="precioaplicable" maxlength="1" placeholder="Indicar el nº de precio aplicable al cliente">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Días pago:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="diaspago" id="diaspago" maxlength="25" placeholder="Días de pago del cliente (ej:30/45/60)">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Descuento comercial %:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dtocomercial" id="dtocomercial" maxlength="3" placeholder="Indicar solo número, sin %">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Descuento pronto pago:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dtoppago" id="dtoppago" maxlength="3" placeholder="Indicar solo número, sin %">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Financiación:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="financiacion" id="financiacion" maxlength="3" placeholder="Indicar el porcentaje de recargo por financiación (sin %)">
                          </div>                          
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelarform()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Cancelar</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--Fin centro -->
                  </div><!-- /.box -->
              </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
      </section><!-- /.content -->

    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!--Fin-Contenido-->
<?php
}
else
{
  require 'noacceso.php';
}
require 'footer.php';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/clienteok.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        //$('#provincia').on('change',function(){
            $('#provincia').change(function(data){
            data.preventDefault();
            var provinciaID = $(this).val();
            //var provinciaID = this.value;
            var data = {'provinciaID': provinciaID};
            if(provinciaID){
                //alert(provinciaID);
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'../ajax/clientes.php?op=selectMunicipio',
                    data: data,
                    //data:provinciaID={provinciaID : provinciaID},
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    success: function(data){
                    //success:function(html){

                        $("#municipio").append(data);
                        $("#municipio").html(data);
                        $('#municipio').selectpicker('refresh');

                    }
                        });
                            }
                        });
                                });
</script>
<?php 
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

2) Here is the PHP file that recieves the data sent with the js on change event:

case "selectMunicipio":

```
    require_once "../modelos/Municipios.php";

    $municipio = new Municipio();
    //$arrayres = array();
    if (empty($_POST['provinciaID'])) 
    { 
        $provinciaID="1";
        } 
    else { 
        $provinciaID=$_POST['provinciaID'];
        }


    $rspta = $municipio->select($provinciaID);

    while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object())
            {
                echo '<option value=' . $reg->id . '>' . $reg->municipio . '</option>';

            }


    break;
```

As I said the echo is working. In response section using Firebug I see:
Alfoz de LloredoAmpuero and so on. 
So my doubt is, what do I need to do in my js to add the result of the echo to ('#municipios')?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I did something wrong, this is my first post here.

Comment: When the data is returned from the ajax call, you're appending it to the element. Then you're replacing that element entirely with the data from the ajax call. Open google chrome tools and inspect the form elements after the ajax call to see.

Comment: You are not echoing JSON from your endpoint, but simply plain text. That causes the parser to fail and not inject anything into your `<select>` element.

Comment: Thanks @Terry ¡ Your tip drove me to the solution. Just tried removing datatype: 'json' from my JS code and now selectpicker works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response you get from your backend is formatted like

```
<option value="example1">Example 1</option>
<option value="example2">Example 2</option>
<option value="example2">Example 2</option>
```

Then you should be good to go with

```
$("#municipio").html(data).selectpicker('refresh');
```

This would empty all options in your `<select>`, filling it with your new options and refreshing the picker. Presuming the `.selectpicker('refresh')` works as you'd expect.

Optionally, you can use `console.log(data);` in your success function to see exactly what comes back from your Ajax request. That way you know if you're getting the right data back.

I've made a fiddle to show how this works:

https://jsfiddle.net/w2cgccn7/

Comment: And I am not able to see console.log :( Maybe any problem with brackets?

Comment: @EndikaTapiaLópez Do you have any errors in your console? If you do, solve those first.

Comment: @EndikaTapiaLópez I've updated my answer with a jsfiddle link, it simulates what you want in the most basic way.

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution to my problem in order to help other people. The problem was that AJAX sent values in AJAX but the PHP returned plain text, so the options were not added to the selectpicker of the form. I solved it removing data type: 'json' from the AJAX and now it works fine. The code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#provincia').change(function(data){
                data.preventDefault();
                var provinciaID = $(this).val();
                var data = {'provinciaID': provinciaID};

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'../ajax/clientes.php?op=selectMunicipio',
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        success: function(data){
                        $("#municipio").html(data);
                        $('#municipio').selectpicker('refresh');
                        }
                    });
                });
    });

   </script>
```

My case for processing data recieved from the AJAX in other PHP file:

```
    case "selectMunicipio":

    require_once "../modelos/Municipios.php";
    $municipio = new Municipio();
    if (empty($_POST['provinciaID'])) 
    { 
        $provinciaID="1";
        } 
    else { 
        $provinciaID=$_POST['provinciaID'];
        }

    $rspta = $municipio->select($provinciaID);

    while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object())
            {
                echo '<option value=' . $reg->id . '>' . $reg->municipio . '</option>'; 

            }

    break;
```

}

And finally here is my select function in other PHP. It is a function I did for a class called Municipio

```
    public function select($provinciaID)
{

    $sql="SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE provincia='$provinciaID'"; 
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);

}
```